# How to expand a subitems of a ListView when click into a ListView item

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I'm trying to expand a ListView subitem when i click into listview item without code, see the estructure:

```
TListView
      |
      |_Item-01
              |
              |_SubItem01
              |
              |_SubItem02
```

I need show the subitems when click in Item-01 but, when i add a ListView in my project and add the Items and the subitems and run the program, clicking into item-01 nothing happens, What is missing? Should not it be automatic? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sub items in a list view are only visible in columns when the list view is in report view style. The sub items are displayed in a row, the same row that contains the main item caption. Think of Explorer in Details view mode.

So, you've got the wrong control. You need a tree view rather than a list view. Either the built in tree view control or the excellent virtual tree view control.

Comment: xD, David Heffernan, you can not be a human. Thanks man, very much!

Comment: Thanks for the, er, compliment!  ;-)

Comment: <Daft Punk>Rock, robot rock
Rock, robot rock
Rock, robot rock
Rock, robot rock</Daft Punk> ;)